# Default email signing with OS X Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, ssl, gpg

I have both a GPG key and an SSL certificate. I am able to sign emails by choosing OpenPGP or S/MIME in the upper right corner of the window:

[image: Signing drop-down]

I can then activate the signing by clicking the appropriate icon:

[image]

Now my question(s):

- is it possible to sign by default? (always unless specified)
- is it possible to sign by default only for a given account?

**Edit 1**

The ideal setup with three accounts would be

1. **account 1 always signs with S/MIME (the address is in the S/MIME certificate)**
2. account 2 always signs with GPG (the address is in the GPG certificate)
3. account 3 do not sign (the address is not present in any certificate)

**Edit 2**

The priority is the S/MIME certificate, I could also live without GPG where only account 1 is using the S/MIME certificate by default.

**Edit 3**

I was now able to set S/MIME as the default (see [*Define the security method to be used*, in the GPGMail 2 hidden settings FAQ](http://support.gpgtools.org/kb/faq-gpgmail/gpgmail-2-hidden-settings#define-the-default-security-method-to-be-used-)). When I then switch to account 2 (the one with the GPG key) the default falls back to GPG (as the address of account 2 is not present in the S/MIME certificate).

```
defaults write org.gpgtools.gpgmail DefaultSecurityMethod -int 2
```

So far so good, now I just have to find out how to sign by default with S/MIME (and not with GPG)

Comment: OS X Mail.app default behaviour is to keep the last signature button state for all new mails of an account if an S/MIME certificate for the current account is present. If that doesn’t happen for you, I suspect the GPG plug-in is to blame. What happens when you enable GPG’s hidden [Enable/Disable Sign by default](http://support.gpgtools.org/kb/gpgmail-faq/gpgmail-2-hidden-settings#enable-disable-sign-by-default) preference?

Comment: This preference is no longer hidden. Enabling it enables Sign By Default for both S/MIME and GPG. (which is what I was looking for when arriving at this question)

Comment: @GhostLyrics What I would like it to be able to handle both separately: S/MIME enabled by default and GPG disabled by default.

Comment: "is it possible to sign by default? (always unless specified)"
Yes. This is set via GPG.

Comment: Mail.app already does what you are requesting. I have email accounts that use S/MIME and some that use GPG.  When I select to use the email address configured for GPG, the GPG sign is enabled by default for signing.  When I select to use the email address configured for S/MIME, the S/MIME signing is enabled by default.

Comment: @kopischke Thank you that was the right hint in my case! Works like a charm.

Comment: @kopischke "OS X Mail.app default behaviour is to keep the last signature button state for all new mails of an account if an S/MIME certificate for the current account is present." this was the information I was looking for, thanks. That's still correct here in 2024. There is no setting in MacOS Mail settings to S/MIME sign or not by default. Instead it just remembers the "sign yes or no" setting (the little blue or gray badge in the Subject line field that says "Click to digitally sign this message" on hover) from the last time you composed a message.

Answer (score 1):

I have some email accounts that use S/MIME and some that use GPG. When I select to use the email address configured for GPG, GPG email signing is enabled by default. When I select to use the email address configured for S/MIME, the S/MIME email signing is enabled by default.

I had to enable some settings in the GPG preference section of Mail.app, but nothing else.

[image]
[image]
[image]